# Calculating percentage area within each cell using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I would like to quantify the percentage area covered by different categorical values (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) within each cell. The cells are defined by layer_1 while the categorical values are in layer_2.

Is there a specific tool or tool combination that I can use in ArcGIS to achieve this?

Hopefully the image gives a good example of what I mean.

I am looking at the spatial join tool + pivot tool to see if this can be done.

I am running ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop (Advanced) with extensions for Spatial Analyst, XTools Pro and Geostatistical Analyst.

[image]

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  My choice would be to use the Intersect tool, and then an ArcPy cursor, but someone else may offer a non-coding way.

Comment: The easiest way is to convert the polygon to raster and use Tabulate Area under Spatial Analyst. It will calculate the area under each polygon grid.

Comment: @PolyGeo yes, non-coding way to start would be better for me.

Comment: If you have vector data, then Tabulate Intersection and Pivot table is the way...

Comment: Please see this, http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm, even the drawings are the same :)

Comment: I think @fatih_dur means http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/tabulate-intersection.htm (because you are using ArcMap rather than ArcGIS Pro - doc may or may not be identical) - but Tabulate Intersection needs an Advanced level license.

Comment: You are right @PolyGeo, it has become Google's default search order behaviour, Pro at the top and then you need to scroll down to find right or LATEST desktop version. I can confirm that the documentation and the the tool's working as identical to what desktop version says. OP indicated having an advanced licence of 10.3.1!

Comment: @fatih_dur to try and get around those search results (not sure if Esri or Google to blame) I am starting to routinely drop "desktop 10.4" on the end of my search.  It seems to help.  I'd overlooked specification by the asker of their license level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have Advanced license, I think the easiest solution is to use @fatih_dur's solution. But you have to make sure you don't have overlapping polygons, as this will produce larger areas than actual.

Personally, I prefer to use [Tabulate Area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) to avoid the problem of overlapping polygons. Also this solution might be efficient in case of the absence of ArcGIS Advanced License. To use Tabulate Area, you need Spatial Analyst license, and you need to convert the categorical polygons into raster with cell size of fair resolution. It will calculate the area under each polygon grid. However, the grid should be polygon feature class not polyline.

Comment: +1 i also like tabulate area tool, however it won't handle overlapping zones, polygons because internally arcgis converts them to raster